# Update list of data using REST api

Tags: flutter, rest

hi am a beginner with flutter and am trying to build a app and in that app i want to let the user update a data that he can accede from a list so when he press on a one of the list item it takes him to a new page where he have more details and he can update some stuff there using REST Api
i dont know how to do that exactly if anyone can help pls
this is the detail page where i one the user to be able to update

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Classes/demandes.dart';

class SrDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Sr sr;
  SrDetailsScreen({Key? key, required this.sr}) : super(key: key);
  List<String> Status = ['En cours', 'done', 'cloturé'];
  String? selecteditem = 'status';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "TICKET ID : ${sr.attributes.ticketid.content} ",
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Ticket id:\n            ${sr.attributes.ticketid.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'Reported by :\n ${sr.attributes.reportedby.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'status :\n ${sr.attributes.status.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'status date :\n ${sr.attributes.statusdate.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'Description:\n ${sr.attributes.description?.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                ""
                'assetnum :\n ${sr.attributes.assetnum?.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'location :\n ${sr.attributes.location?.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'assetsiteid:\n ${sr.attributes.assetsiteid?.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              const Divider(),
              Text(
                'DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION :\n ${sr.attributes.DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION?.content}',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              OutlinedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  label: const Text("Save")),
            ])));
  }
}
```

and thank you

Comment: try call setstate after update variable on widget

Comment: Sorry for late. What are you updating. All are simple Text. For update you have to select or input any thing that is not looking in your code. For input use TextField and update it on same id.

Comment: is there anyway i can contact you ? i really ned some help

Comment: If need ny help, share ur nydesk id

Answer (score 0):

Surround this with setstate(){}

```
setState(() {
      icon: const Icon(
         Icons.edit,
         size: 18,
        ),
       label: const Text("Save")),
    });
```